# Find all cycles in the directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, tarjans-algorithm

Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm  can only find fundamental cycles or all cycles that are in the graph ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you need this for?  I cannot imaging any actual problem where this would be a useful approach.

Comment: I need to find all the cycles in the graph. The Tarjan's algorithm is not specified  the following point: it finds all cycles or only the fundamental cycles in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot find all the cycles as long as it runs in O(V + E) (Polynomial time). If it could, it could solve hamiltonian cycle problem in polynomial time but this problem is NP-hard.

Comment: The idea of the answer is correct but inaccurate. The fact is we do not know if NP-Hard problems can be solved polynomially. Note however that this problem is much harder, and even if P=NP cannot be solved polynomially since the size of output is exponential in the input (could be exponential number of cycles).